# user have to either not input zip code and it should be of length 5(numbers only) but in my code else if statement line is not working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
/* user have to either not input zip code and it should be of length 5(numbers only) but in my code else if statement line is not working. */
<script>
   function max(){ /* this is the function to check the input feilds and if find mistake alert the message in to an alert box */    
      _aa=document.getElementById("s1").value
      if(_aa.length>10)
         xx="name should be less then or equal to 10 characters"
      else xx=""
         _bb=document.getElementById("s2").value
      if(_bb.length>10)
         yy="last name should be less then or equal to 10 characters"
      else yy=""
         _cc=document.getElementById("s3").value
      if(_cc.length<6)
         zz="street adress should be greater then or equal to 6 characters"
      else zz=""
         _dd=document.getElementById("s4").value
      if(isNaN(_dd)){jj="fill"}
      else if(_dd.length!=5 || _dd.length!=0){jj="fill"} \\this does'nt work
      else{jj=""}
      alert([xx,yy,zz,jj]);
   }
  </script>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form >
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="middle">CHECKOUT FORM <hr/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>First name:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text"id="s1"/ ></td>
            <td><p id="a1"></p></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Last name:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text"id="s2"  / ></td>
            <td><p id="a2"></p></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Street Address:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text"id="s3" maxlength=""  / ></td>
            <td><p id="a3"></p></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>State:</strong></td>
            <td><select><option>selet state</option></select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Zip Code:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="s4"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number"id="s5" min="" max=""  / ></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="middle">ORDER INFORMATION <hr/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Order Subtotal:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number"id="s6" min="" max="" / ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Shipping Option:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s7"value="6.75" name="bt" onclick="calculate(this.value)"/ >UPPS6.75</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s8" value="8.55" name="bt" onclick="calculate(this.value)" / >UPS8.55</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s9"value="10.00" name="bt" onclick="calculate(this.value)" / >FEDERAL EXPRESS10.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Shipping cost:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number"id="s10" min="" max="" / ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Tax(5%):</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number"id="s11" min="" max=""  / ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>TOTAL:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number"id="s12" min="" max=""  / ></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="middle">PAYMENT INFORMATION <hr/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Credit Card:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s13"value="" name="bn"  / >American Express</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s14" value="" name="bn"  / >Diners Club</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s15"value="" name="bn"  / >Discover</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s16"value="" name="bn"  / >MasterCard</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="radio"id="s17"value="" name="bn"  / >Visa</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Card Number:</strong></td>
            <td><input type="number"id="s18" min="" max="" / ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><strong>Expiration:</strong></td>
            <td colspan="2"><select id="s19"><option>01</option></select>/
            <select><option>2011</option></select>
            </td>                                                                        
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="max()" >place</button></td>
            <td><input type="submit"id="s21" value="Cancel" / ></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: some thoughts: 1. syntax error somehwere, 2. expiration date in past.

Answer (score 1):

variable declaration was wrong

1. Declare all your element value in function start
2. And declare the all `_aa` with variable like `var _aa`
3. Don't forget to add `{}` in if else condition

**Why is not working?**

Because you are declare the `_dd` in `if (_cc.length < 6)` in else condition .`_dd` always null until `if (_cc.length < 6)` else statement execute

```js
function max() {
  var _aa = document.getElementById("s1").value
  var _bb = document.getElementById("s2").value
  var _cc = document.getElementById("s3").value
  var _dd = document.getElementById("s4").value
  if (_aa.length > 10) {
    var xx = "name should be less then or equal to 10 characters"
  } else {
    xx = ""

  }
  if (_bb.length > 10) {
    var yy = "last name should be less then or equal to 10 characters"
  } else {
    yy = "";

  }
  if (_cc.length < 6) {
    var zz = "street adress should be greater then or equal to 6 characters"
  } else {
    zz = ""

  }
  if (isNaN(_dd)) {
    var jj = "fill"
  } else if (_dd.length != 5 || _dd.length != 0) {
    jj = "fill length"
  } else {
    jj = ""
  }
  console.log([xx, yy, zz, jj]);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="middle">CHECKOUT FORM
        <hr/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>First name:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="s1" /></td>
      <td>
        <p id="a1"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Last name:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="s2" /></td>
      <td>
        <p id="a2"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Street Address:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="s3" maxlength="" /></td>
      <td>
        <p id="a3"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>State:</strong></td>
      <td><select><option>selet state</option></select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Zip Code:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="s4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="s5" min="" max="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="middle">ORDER INFORMATION
        <hr/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Order Subtotal:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="s6" min="" max="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Shipping Option:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s7" value="6.75" name="bt" onclick="calculate(this.value)" />UPPS6.75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s8" value="8.55" name="bt" onclick="calculate(this.value)" />UPS8.55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s9" value="10.00" name="bt" onclick="calculate(this.value)" />FEDERAL EXPRESS10.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Shipping cost:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="s10" min="" max="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Tax(5%):</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="s11" min="" max="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>TOTAL:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="s12" min="" max="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="middle">PAYMENT INFORMATION
        <hr/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Credit Card:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s13" value="" name="bn" />American Express</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s14" value="" name="bn" />Diners Club</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s15" value="" name="bn" />Discover</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s16" value="" name="bn" />MasterCard</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="radio" id="s17" value="" name="bn" />Visa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Card Number:</strong></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="s18" min="" max="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Expiration:</strong></td>
      <td colspan="2"><select id="s19"><option>01</option></select>/
        <select><option>2011</option></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button type="button" onclick="max()">place</button></td>
      <td><input type="submit" id="s21" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```